# How to combine multiple rows to one row

Tags: python, pandas

In Python DataFrame, for one MemberID, I had multiple rows where there are some null for certain columns like below:

```
   Date   MemberID    Name      Education      Occupation    Gender
0  2017/01  001         A          Nan            Student      M
1  2017/02  001         A          Graduate         Nan        M
2  2017/03  001         A          Nan            Physician    M
3  2017/01  002         B          College          Nan        F
4  2017/02  002         B          Nan            Professor    Nan
5  2017/03  002         B          PHD              Nan        F
```

I would like to clean the data with output as below:

Fill the NULL value with latest information for the same MemberID.

```
   Date    MemberID    Name    Education      Occupation    Gender
0  2017/03   001         A      Graduate       Physician       M
1  2017/03   002         B      PHD            Professor       F
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.groupby` and `.last`:

```
df.groupby('MemberID').last()
```

output:

```
            Date    Name    Education   Occupation  Gender
MemberID                    
     1     2017/03    A      Graduate   Physician      M
     2     2017/03    B           PHD   Professor      F
```

Comment: You don’t need the initial fillna. When using last in a groupby context it will choose the last non null

Comment: @piRSquared That's amazing.

Comment: Thanks you all, I had hundreds of thousand rows with 20 more columns, it will help me greatly.